Spring Boot 3.3.2 with Spring Security 6.3.1 issue (no support of auth0-spring-security-api with Spring Framework 3.3.2)
I am to trying upgrade my project to Spring Boot 3.3.2 version and the Spring Security version is 6.3.1.
In the code, the JwtWebSecurityConfigurer class is used to set the below fields.
JwtWebSecurityConfigurer
        .forRS256(env.getRequiredProperty("AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE"), 
         env.getRequiredProperty("AUTH0_API_ISSUER"))
        .configure(http);

The package com.auth0.spring.security.api.JwtWebSecurityConfigurer is used and it is derived from dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth0-spring-security-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>

The problem is I cannot use auth0-spring-security-api with Spring Framework 3.3.2 because it is not compatible. I would like to know the equivalent library to use instead of auth0-spring-security-api along with Spring framework 3.3.2.
I am getting the below error:
[http-nio-8082-exec-4] ERROR [dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet 
  [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest 
  org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpRequestResponseHolder.getRequest()'
 atcom.auth0.spring.security.api.BearerSecurityContextRepository.loadContext(BearerSecurityContextRepository.java:21)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextRepository.lambda$loadDeferredContext$0(SecurityContextRepository.java:81)



Spring versions are being mixed you need to check the auth0 for a support matrix between Spring Boot and what versions of their library support.

The below piece of code in securityFilter is giving 403 Forbidden issue after resolving the above error. I checked the jwt token and it has the scope : front:read. I'm providing the code of setting http. http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.requestMatchers("/v1/sss/producer/**").hasAuthority("front:read")
.anyRequest()
.authenticated())
.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder())))
.oauth2ResourceServer(
oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())))
) }


Instead of using the auth0 library which is not compatible with Spring Boot 3.3.2 with Spring Security 6.3.1 issue , the spring boot libraries are used.

Old dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth0-spring-security-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>

Replaced dependency:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>


JwtWebSecurityConfigurer
.forRS256(env.getRequiredProperty("AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE"),
env.getRequiredProperty("AUTH0_API_ISSUER"))
.configure(http);

is replaced with
    http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder())))

OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator() {
        return new AudienceValidator();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder) JwtDecoders
                .fromIssuerLocation(env.getProperty("AUTH0_API_ISSUER"));// issuer name

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = audienceValidator();

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(env.getProperty("AUTH0_API_ISSUER"));
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

        return jwtDecoder;
    }

    class AudienceValidator implements OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> {
        OAuth2Error error = new OAuth2Error("custom_code", "Custom error message", null);

        @Override
        public OAuth2TokenValidatorResult validate(Jwt jwt) {
            if (jwt.getAudience().contains(env.getRequiredProperty("AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE"))) {
                return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.success();
            } else {
                return OAuth2TokenValidatorResult.failure(error);
            }
        }
    }


Application.properties is set with
spring.boot.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri = issueruri
spring.boot.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.audiences = audience
spring.boot.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jws-algorithms = RS512
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER


4.Also the antMatchers are replaced withrequestMatchers
http
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder())))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                        .requestMatchers("/requests")
                        .hasAuthority(API_REQUEST_READ_AUDIENCE).requestMatchers("/v1.0/**")
                        .authenticated())


After getting 403 Forbidden issue with **WWW- Autheticate Bearer error="insufficient_scope", error_description="The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token."**, the changes are made in to add the "SCOPE_"
http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.requestMatchers("/requests").hasAuthority("SCOPE_"+API_REQUEST_READ_AUDIENCE)


Now the application is upgraded with Spring Boot 3.3.2 with Spring Security 6.3.1 issue. The crucial part is to understand the Spring security flow as given in https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html

You don't need the starter from Auth0 at all.
With just the official starter
Base configuration
The configuration is rather simple, even if you want to add the validation for the audience in the JWT decoder.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: ${AUTH0_API_ISSUER}
          audiences: ${AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE}

Without the need for authorities mapping, that should be enough (no Java security conf required).
Adding authorities mapping
Let's say that you have added a login flow in Auth0 to add user roles to access tokens and that their payload look like the following:
{
  "https://c4-soft.com/user": {
    "roles": [
      "BARMAN",
      "FAULT_EDITOR",
      "NICE",
      "USER_ROLES_EDITOR"
    ]
  },
  "iss": "https://dev-ch4mpy.eu.auth0.com/",
  "aud": [
    "demo.c4-soft.com",
    "https://dev-ch4mpy.eu.auth0.com/userinfo"
  ],
  "scope": "openid email",
  ...
}

You'll need something like the following security configuration:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConf {
  private static String PRIVATE_CLAIMS = "https://c4-soft.com/user";
  private static String ROLES_CLAIM = "roles";

  interface AuthoritiesConverter extends Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {}

  @Bean
  AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter() {
    return jwt -> {
      final var privateClaims = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().getOrDefault(PRIVATE_CLAIMS, Map.of());
      final var rolesClaim = (List<String>) privateClaims.getOrDefault(ROLES_CLAIM, List.of());
      return rolesClaim.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).map(GrantedAuthority.class::cast).toList();
    };
  }

  @Bean
  JwtAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter(Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> authoritiesConverter) {
    final var authenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    authenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(authoritiesConverter);
    return authenticationConverter;
  }

  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain resourceServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken> authenticationConverter) throws Exception {
    http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> {
      oauth2.jwt(resourceServer -> {
        resourceServer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);
      });
    });

    http.sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)).csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> {
      requests.anyRequest().authenticated();
    });

    return http.build();
  }
}

With spring-addons-starter-oidc
Alternatively, you can use "my" starter which eases the configuration of a resource server filter chain with authorities mapping:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.8.8</version>
</dependency>

# properties under spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver are ignored
# instead, use the following:
com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: ${AUTH0_API_ISSUER}
          aud: ${AUTH0_API_AUDIENCE}
          authorities:
            # path are JsonPath expressions
          - path: $['https://c4-soft.com/user']['roles']
          - path: $.permissions

And that's all, no need for Java configuration to map Auth0 roles to Spring authorities!
This starter is even more useful in the case of a client with oauth2Login as it allows to configure the audience parameter to add to the authorization requests with just properties (in addition to many other things like cookie-based CSRF protection, logout configuration, post-login and post-logout URIs, ...). Such clients might be server-side rendered applications (with Thymeleaf for instance) or Spring Cloud Gateway configured as an OAuth2 BFF for a single-page (or mobile) application.

I tried with spring-addons-starter-oidc. But , I am getting 403 error with the reason stated in response header as , WWW- Autheticate
Bearer error="insufficient_scope", error_description="The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token.", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"

It seems that the user is not granted with the authority expected by a security rule. Some possible reasons: The role is not in the token (check token payload), authorities mapping is misconfigured (check JsonPath in application properties), or hasRole('FOO') is used with a mapped authority having another case or not being prefixed with ROLE_ (hasRole('foo' ) expects ROLE_foo as authority and hasAuthority('fOo) expects fOo).
